# What are instanton fugacities?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, instantons

I have seen this term many times in various papers but I could not find anywhere a good explanation on what [instanton fugacity](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=instanton+fugacity) is. Can you explain and provide some reference if possible please?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Which papers?

Comment: Fugacity is a notion derivable from a chemical potential, so shouldn't the instanton fugacity simply be the fugacity associated with the chemical potential of the instantons? Said another way, if you think of the instantons as simply another particle species, they should have a corresponding chemical potential and fugacity.

Comment: For example http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.6603